# Delphi SSL connection using a certificate on a smart card

Tags: delphi, ssl, smartcard, pki, pkcs#11

I'm trying to access a certain API and I have been provided with a smart card which contains the certificate that I'm supposed to use to establish a SSL connection with the said API. I'm trying to do this through a Delphi appliction.

The following is the info of the certificate:

> The certificate used to establish a secure connection is stored on a
> smart card and it can be accessed from the PKI Applet using PKSC#11
> API. The certificate is loaded in the slot / token structure on the
> PKI Applet. After the certificate is extracted from the smart card (in
> DER format) it can be used as a standard X.509 certificate for TLS/SSL
> and HTTPS protocols.

I'm able to extract the certificate (via pkcs11CertificateStorage tool from SecureBlackbox) but I'm hvaing trouble using it for a SSL connection with Delphi.

Here's a simplified version of what I'm doing to attach the certificate to the request (using ipWorks REST component):

```
var
CertStorage: TsbxCertificateStorage;
ipwREST1: TipwREST;
// ...
CertStorage.Open('pkcs11://user:' + Pin + '@/' + StorageFilename + '?slot=0'+ RO);
ipwREST1.SSLCertEncodedB := CertStorage.Certificates[0].Bytes;
ipwREST1.Get('https://...');
```

The error that I get from the REST component:

> 273: Could not acquire security credentials: error 0x8009030E

Which led me to the error explanation by the component developer:

> When using a certificate for client authentication, ensure the certificate's private keys are accessible. The certificate in the Windows certificate store must contain the corresponding private keys, and be marked as exportable.

and I'm not sure how to interpret this.

I've tried saving the certificate in a file, using openSSL to convert to PEM and attaching it in other ways but with no success.
I feel like I'm missing something in my approach. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Do a step by step approach: if you can save it to a DER file, can OpenSSL then interpret it, i.e. `openssl x509 -inform der -in CERTIFICATE.der -text -noout`? See [PEM and DER format](https://www.ssl.com/guide/pem-der-crt-and-cer-x-509-encodings-and-conversions/) and identify at which point you fail. AND: more than one card slot may exist. Your code example is pointless without types/variable declarations.

Comment: @AmigoJack thanks. You're right about variable types, I've edited that now. OpenSSL can interpret it with the command you've provided and I've tried converting it to PEM before, including the whole certificate chain etc but to no avail. 
Right now everything I looked at points to something with the certificate private key but that's where I lack knowledge about this and can't find much info about it elsewhere online.